# weibel's exercise 6.2.4

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra

[image]

I think we should use the corollary to solve this problem.

For the first question, I think we can use the property that  $J$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ module with a basis ${s-1,t-1}$. Hence $J\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}= 2\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}$.

But I don't know how to solve the second question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you have written is incorrect : $2\mathbb Z [G] \otimes \mathbb Z'$ is the image of $J \otimes \mathbb Z'$ inside $\mathbb Z [G] \otimes \mathbb Z' \cong \mathbb Z$. So it answers only the first half of the first question. But you are on the right track, and it is only a matter of writing properly the free resolutions given by the corollary for G and for T (the latter is free on one generator), taking tensor products with $\mathbb Z'$, and computing homology.

Comment: @J.Darné The hardest part for me is that I don't know how to find an element which is not zero  in $J\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}\mathbb{Z^{'}}$ but is zero in ${\mathbb{Z}[G]}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}\mathbb{Z^{'}}

Comment: @J.Darné I seem to have already understood a bit of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $J$ is a free $\mathbb Z[G]$-module of rank two (the two generators being $(s-1)$ and $(t-1)$), the tensor product $J \otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]} \mathbb Z'$ is the direct sum of two copies of $\mathbb Z [G] \otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]} \mathbb Z' \cong \mathbb Z$. So the tensor product of the resolution of the trivial representation $0 \rightarrow J \rightarrow \mathbb Z[G] \rightarrow 0$ with $\mathbb Z'$ is:
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow 0.$$
Then you need to understand the middle map. The calculations that you have already done in your question (which are in fact just a reformulation of the definition of $\mathbb Z'$) give you that the two elements $(s-1) \otimes 1$ and $(t-1) \otimes 1$, which form a basis of the source, are both sent to $1 \otimes 2 = 2 (1 \otimes 1)$ in the target, which means that this map identifies with $(m,n) \mapsto 2(m+n)$ (it sends both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to $2$). Its cokernel is thus $\mathbb Z/2$, and its kernel is $\mathbb Z$, as expected (and you can write these generators as the classes of explicit cycles if you like).

For computing the homology $H_*(T, \mathbb Z')$, you have the same resolution (since $T$ is free on one generator), and you can use exactly the same reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the hardest part of the question is how to prove $H_1(G ; \mathbb{Z}^{'}) = \mathbb{Z}$.

We just need to prove that the kernel of $J\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}$ is $\{(s-t) \otimes n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

First it is easy to check that $(s^2-1)\otimes 1=(s-1)(s+1)\otimes 1 =0 \in J \otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}$.

For every $g(s,t)\otimes 1\in  J\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}$ which is zero in $ \mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes \mathbb{Z^{'}}$, we can assume that g(s,t) dones't have constant.

Hence,$g(s,t)=sf_1(s,t)-tf_2(s,t)=t(f_1(s,t)-f_2(s,t))+(s-t)(f_1(s,t))$ with $g(1,1)=$$g(-1,-1)=0$.
We can continue this process for $(f_1(s,t)-f_2(s,t))$.

Ultimately, $\{(s-t) \otimes n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is the kernel.

Comment: If you realize that these tensor products are in fact really simple modules, this part is not really harder that the first one. Your reasoning seems ok, but it also seems to be overly complicated

Comment: In fact, it seems incomplete: you have shown that the kernel is generated by one element, but you need an argument saying that this cyclic abelian group is torsion-free. Which is not hard, but is easier if you understand the module structure ;)